# How can I get bootstrap to alter page CSS instead of lay dormant?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am practicing with bootstrap and I have used firebug to ensure it is loaded but it doesn't affect anything. if i look at the CSS and push the spacebar bootstrap magically works. My page is [here][1].

I am guessing whenever i make an edit in firebug CSS it updates the page but i am confused as to why Bootstrap doesn't work in the first place unless I use firebux to update it.

```
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Works fine after I use firebug to update CSS.
[1]: http://rayd360.kd.io/one/public/index.php/blog#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing a CSS extension on your css file declaration.

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://rayd360.kd.io/one/public/css/bootstrap.min">
```

Is it possible it's not getting parsed correctly? Try putting a .css on the end, and updating your code.

Comment: it is in above body in the header